# How is Tangle Quantum Immune?

Tags: iota-network, tangle, security, signing, quantum-resistant

I was going through the iota tangle documentation and features and found one of the feature mentioned as **Quantum Immune** , so basically looking for resources to understand the quantum immune property of tangle algorithms.

Answer (score 2):

IOTA is what we call 'quantum robust' because of the signature scheme that it uses.

You can find detailed information about signatures on our [documentation portal](https://docs.iota.org/docs/getting-started/0.1/clients/signatures).

Comment: Thanks @Jake for the info